# Extracting information from Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing, text

The format is 
"FirstName LastName Type_Date-Time_ref_PhoneNumber"

All this is a single string

Example: "Yasir Pirkani MCD_20201105-134700_abc123_12345678"

I want to extract Name, Type, Date, Time, ref, Phonenumber from this string.

Comment: Please add some code to show your effort at solving the problem

Comment: Also see [Stackoverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: You could try something like `re.split(re.split('[\s_]+', my_string)`

Comment: Till now I have been able to search for the Date, Time, ref and Phone Number by searching for "_"

text = 'Yasir Pirkani MCD_20201105-134700_abc123_12345678'
x = [i for i in range(len(file)) if file.startswith('_', i)]
date= text[x[0]+1:x[0]+5]
time = file[x[0]+10:x[0]+16]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do so, one of them is using regex.

```
s = "Yasir Pirkani MCD_20201105-134700_abc123_12345678"
splited_s = re.split('[\s_]+', s)
# splited_s -> ['Yasir', 'Pirkani', 'MCD', '20201105-134700', 'abc123', '12345678']
```

Then you can access each element of `splited_s` and adjust it properly

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
a = "Yasir Pirkani MCD_20201105-134700_abc123_12345678"
name = " ".join(a.split(" ")[:2])
Type, Date, ref, Phonenumber = a.replace(name, "").strip().split("_")
Time = Date[Date.find("-")+ 1:]
Date = Date.replace(f"-{Time}", "")
print(name, Type, Date, Time, ref, Phonenumber)
```

That will output

```
('Yasir Pirkani', 'MCD', '20201105', '134700', 'abc123', '12345678')
```